# Get north east corner from east west longitude, north south latitude

Tags: geolocation, maps, latitude-longitude, distance

I have east and west longitude coordinate, and north south latitude coordinate.
Any idea how can I extract west-north, west-south and east north from them?

Comment: Retrieve/split lat/lng and then join what you need.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? what does split means?

Comment: I do not know what you use: javascript, java/android... But for example in Google Maps API bounds are represented as SW and NE LatLng objects. From those objects you can get latitude and longitude using `lat()` and `lng()` methods. From those 4 values you can build necessary coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need combine latitue & longitude to create GeoCoordinates. Thus west-north coordinate position would be your west-longitude + north-latitude, and your west-south would be west-longitude + south-latitude etc.